# Using saved Tensorflow Estimator with C++ API

Tags: python, c++, tensorflow

I have written the Abalone estimator in Python as described in https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/tutorials/estimators/. I wish to save the state of the estimator, then load it in C++ and use it to make predictions.

To save it from Python, I use the `model_dir` parameter in the `tf.contrib.learn.Estimator` constructor, which creates a (text) protobuf file and several checkpoint files. I then use the `freeze_graph.py` tool (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.py) to combine the checkpoint and the protobuf file into a standalone GraphDef file.

I load this file using the C++ API, load some input values into a Tensor, then run the session. The input node in the protobuf file is called 'input' and the output node 'output', and both are placeholder nodes.

```
// ...
std::vector<std::pair<string, tensorflow::Tensor>> inputs = 
{
    {"input", inputTensor}
};

std::vector<tensorflow::Tensor> outputs;

status = pSession->Run(inputs, {"output"}, {}, &outputs);
```

However, since the output node is a placeholder node, this fails since it needs to be fed a value. But you cannot both feed and fetch a node value, so I cannot get access to the output of the estimator. Why is the output node a placeholder node?

What is the best way to save a trained estimator from Python and load it for prediction in C++?